# Can i make a certain value visible to all classes? (Android)

Tags: java, android

I have an app which uses Google Maps and GPScoordinates. I need the current location in multiple classes, and i don't want to use intent.putExtra and getExtra everytime. Can I make a certain value visible to all classes in my app?

Comment: You can use sharedPreferences to store the current value or make a singleton object which will hold the reference to the object.

Comment: You can always have a separate class to hold the values and use that object everywhere in your application. Like a POJO or in simple words, having a class where you have all the getters and setters for all your important variables. You can also have the service class in your case for getting the coordinates and save those coordinates in the getters and setters class and then use them in the class you desire.

Comment: declare that variable as static   ...that's it....nothing else

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this, SharedPreferences is one but I think the best mechanism would be to use a global context. You do this by overriding Application with a custom class.

```
public class GlobalContext extends Application{

    private String mSomething;

    public String getSomething() {
        return mSomething;
    }

    public void setSomething(String value) {
       mSomething = value;
    }
```

That is then used in your manifest

```
<application
        android:name="com.example.GlobalContext"
        ...
```

Then in all of your activities a call to getApplicationContext will return the instance of that class.

```
final GlobalContext globalContext = (GlobalContext) getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: Thank you for your responses! But when i use "final GlobalContext globalContext = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();" it says: Cannot resolve symbol "GlobalClass". What to do?

Comment: @VladIancu Sorry (GlobalContext) not GlobalClass.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say this answer is better than the answers posted above, but why not use a Singleton class?

eg

```
public class GPSValues{
    public static GPSValues INSTANCE = new GPSValues();

    protected double lat, lon, alt;

    public static GPSValues getInstance(){
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    public double getLat(){
        return lat;
    }
.
.
.
}
```

Then to use it, just do GPSValues.getInstance().setLat(number) and double  lat  = GPSValues.getInstance().lat

Answer (score 0):

I think a very "hacky" way to go about it is just make the information you want to share public. Then access it from another activity, such as `var coordinates = MainActivity.GPScoordinates` This isn't the best approach, but its certainly simple.